# Is it possible to decompile the jar file obfuscated by proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, decompiling

I have jar file which is used in my android project. I have obfuscated the the jar file using Proguard tool. Is it possible to decompile the jar file and get the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

ProGuard cannot prevent reverse engineering on the bytecode, but, if properly configured, it will make the understanding of the decompiled code much more difficult.